# perl6: access values in a multidimensional variable

Tags: multidimensional-array, raku

Perl6 Twitter module gives a multidimensional variable with the tweets from a search query. This code:

```
%tweets<statuses>[0]<metadata><iso_language_code>.say;
%tweets<statuses>[0]<created_at>.say;
```

prints:

```
es
Fri May 04 13:54:47 +0000 2018
```

The following code prints the 'created_at' value of the tweets from the search query.

```
for @(%tweets<statuses>) -> $tweet {
  $tweet<created_at>.say;
}
```

Is there a better syntax to access the values of the variable %tweets?

Thanks!

Comment: Better how?  It would depend on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Maybe converting %tweets into JSON and parsing it, to be able to get the value of 'iso_language_code' or 'created_at'.

Comment: What do you mean by "better syntax"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the question is whether there is a shorter syntax for hash indexing with literal keys than `<...>`, then no, that's as short as it gets. In Perl 6, there's no conflation of the hash data structure with object methods/attributes/properties (unlike with JavaScript, for example, where there is no such distinction, so `.` is used for both).

There are plenty of ways to get rid of repetition and boilerplate, however. For example:

```
%tweets<statuses>[0]<metadata><iso_language_code>.say;
%tweets<statuses>[0]<created_at>.say;
```

Could be written instead as:

```
given %tweets<statuses>[0] {
    .<metadata><iso_language_code>.say;
    .<created_at>.say;
}
```

This is using the topic variable `$_`. For short, simple, loops, that can also be used, like this:

```
for @(%tweets<statuses>) {
    .<created_at>.say;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is what I needed to know! Cheers!